# Como convierto '89.00' a un numero real?

Tags: float

yo utilizo `float` para convertir `'89.00'` a `89.0` pero como ven el problema es que necesito dos ceros en el codigo.....

¿alguien me podria ayudar?

(primera vez en **stakoverflow**)

```
n = float(input("ingrese el numero: "))
lista = [83,45,64]
lista0 = [lista[0] + n,
         lista[1] + n,
         lista[2] + n]
pro = (sum(lista0)/len(lista0))

lista1 = [lista0[0],
         lista0[1],
         lista0[2],
         pro]
lista2 = [ "{:.2f}".format(lista1[0]),
          "%.2f" % round(lista1[1], 2),
          "%.2f" % round(lista1[2], 2),
          "%.2f" % round(lista1[3], 2),]
l3 = [(lista2[0]),
      float(lista2[1]),
      float(lista2[2]),
      float(lista2[3])]

print(l3)
```

Comment: El número es el número. La representación con decimales o no es al convertirlo a string

Comment: Gracias...por tu ayuda 